# Unable to imort OpenCV in python

Tags: opencv

I've been trying to install OpenCV in ubuntu 16.04 for the past 2 days. I followed various tutorials, but couldn't get it to work. Right now I'm trying to install it [from here.](http://www.daslhub.org/unlv/wiki/doku.php?id=opencv_install_ubuntu). Everything works fine until the instruction

```
cmake .
```

This instruction produces the output

```
kvs@Hunter:~/Downloads/OpenCV_Capstone/opencv-3.3.0/samples$ cmake .
-- OpenCV ARCH: 
-- OpenCV RUNTIME: 
-- OpenCV STATIC: ON
CMake Warning at /home/kvs/opencv-3.0.0/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake:166 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has no binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

  You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:55 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /home/kvs/opencv-3.0.0/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/kvs/Downloads/OpenCV_Capstone/opencv-3.3.0/samples/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

And below is the instruction preceding `cmake` and its output

```
$ pkg-config --libs opencv

kvs@Hunter:~/Downloads/OpenCV_Capstone$ pkg-config --libs opencv
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core
```

There's something written in the error about what I should do but my knowledge about that is limited. How can I remove the error?

Please note that the tutorial uses OpenCV 3.2.0 whereas I'm trying to install OpenCV 3.3.0. Can this be a cause of the problem? Also, How can I remove opencv and all its dependencies from my system? Synaptic package manager tells me that there are broken packages to be fixed before removing anything but when I search for those broken packages nothing shows up.

2.I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

with the output

```
kvs@Hunter:~$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libopencv-dev is already the newest version (2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but still I'm not able to import the library in the console

```
>>> from cv2.cv import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

3. As mentioned in the comment I also tried these instructions from [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) as suggested in comment. After running the script, OpenCV 3.3.0 is installed.

```
 Done. The new package has been installed and saved to

 /home/kvs/OpenCV/OpenCV/opencv-3.3.0/build/build_20170906-1_amd64.deb

 You can remove it from your system anytime using: 

      dpkg -r build
```

but I'm still not able to import it in python3. doesn't work in python 2.7 either.

```
kvs@Hunter:~/OpenCV$ python3
Python 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

How do I import it? What's wrong with the installation? I followed everything from the above instructions.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV and also http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Comment: @MichaelBay I followed the instructions from (help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) and terminal says the download is complete but when I try to load an image using python with the given command it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

Comment: I meant 'installation complete' instead of 'download complete' in the previous comment.

Comment: have you tried python3 -m pip install opencv-python ? It should be enough, no need to build anything